# LoseLess Compression for Jpegs with ImageResizer

Tags: .net, imageresizer

Can I Losslessly compress an Image using Image Resizer, it seems to have compressed my PNGs really well, but my JPEGs compress the same as my previous code. Around 2% off the loseless compression.

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: Sorry is Lossy compression I am after, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the amount of lossy compression in a .jpeg by specifying the quality of the bitmap when you save it. There should be a parameter for that.

Comment: Yes, the &quality=80 command will let you adjust the compression. Keep in mind that each time you re-compress a jpeg, it gets larger - jpeg artifacts are hard to compress. The higher-quality the original, the smaller the result can be.

Comment: Hello, Ive already set the quality to a lower setting, once that is processed and rendered, Ive uploaded this to an online compressor to compare - and it is still larger - so they are doing something in the compressor that appears to be extra. 
Dim ResizeInstructions As New ImageResizer.Instructions
ResizeInstructions.JpegQuality = 70

Comment: If you start without exif data and/or thumbnail and add it when you save, the file will get a little bigger.

Answer (score 0):

This online compressor allows much smaller files: https://compressor.io/compress, Google Page Speed indicates that elements with the compression flag set there is still compression available.Losslessly compressing http://www.example.com…ogos/small/values-exchange_h340_w340.jpg could save 1.7KiB (21% reduction). - Quality for Jpeg is set to 75%, previously 70% but that still reported that I needed more compression. Not sure how to remove these extra bytes.

Basically I want Progressive/Interlaced loading for my Larger images (Set when size is larger WxH>34000000 assumption) and would like to save the files as small as possible, (Lossy or Lossless). I think Ive installed the FreeImage plugin correctly - seems to run with the encoder flag set, (Not running through the managed ImageResizer handler as is currently a modification/upgrade to my existing handler)

The File will be resized on upload, then where applicable variant sizes made available. If the compression does make the file proportionally larger each time (Don't understand this), then there will be a maximum of two resizes (On Upload) and then from that master copy to a smaller size.